# Can't update a SQL table in Visual Basic 2010: getting error "keyword not supported 'port'"

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I can't update my SQL Table in Visual Basic 2010. Still getting error keyword not supported 'port'. Here is  code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox15.Click
    Dim con As String = "server=db4free.net;port=3306; user id=12345; password=12345;database=12345"
    Dim myConnection As New SqlConnection(con)
    Dim rows As Integer
    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand()
    Try
        myConnection.Open()
        myCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE tabel1 SET name='" & "12345" & "', username='" & "12345" & "', password='" & "12345" & "', email='" & "12345" & "', phone='" & "+1-xxx-xxxx" & "', score='" & "16" & "', level='" & "2" & "', country='" & "USA" & "', age='" & "17" & "', bio='" & "1235" & "' Where username = '" & "1235" & "'"
        rows = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As SqlException
    Finally
        myConnection.Close()
        MsgBox("Score is updated")
    End Try
End Sub
```

here is what happened,
[image]

Comment: What exactly is the point of concatenating multiple literal strings?  Why would you use `"Hello" & " " & "World"` instead of `"Hello World"`?  If you're thinking of replacing some of them with variables then think again.  Learn to use parameters instead.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?  Your code uses a `SqlConnection` object, which is only for SQL Server.  If you are using MySQL then you need to download Connector\Net from the MySQL web site and then use a `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection` object to connect.  I believe that the "port" keyword is supported in MySQL connections strings but it is not for SQL Server.  Either way, [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) can show what is and isn't supported.